# Remove complete string with special character

Tags: python-3.x

In a sentence, I want to remove a complete string which contains special characters.

Input is `["i am in jersey1&2","this code is %bdn2*nn"]`

Expected output is `["i am in","this code is"]`

```
import re

Dsp = ["i am in jersey1&2","this code is %bdn2*nn"]

Dsp1 = []

for i in Dsp:
    Dsp = [re.sub('^\W+$'," ",j) for j in i]
    Dsp1.append("".join(Dsp))
```

I got

```
Dsp1 = ["i am in jersey12","this code is bdn2nn"]
```

but the expected output is

```
Dsp1 = ["i am in", "this code is"]
```

Comment: thats because when you do 
`for i in Dsp:`
it will iterate through all the characters in that sentence one by one, that means it wont consider individual string at `i` for every iteration. Why dont you try to split the sentence with delimiter as " " (blank space) then you will have a list of individual strings.
Then you can check individual strings and remove the ones you dont need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting `re.sub` to match and replace on word level, where words are substrings delimited by whitespace within a string. Regular expressions will match on a character level, unless you manage to tell them otherwise (which is a bit complicated) or you split the strings on whitespace before applying a special-character matching regex:

```
Dsp = ["i am in jersey1&2","this code is %bdn2*nn"]
Dsp1 = []

for sentence in Dsp:
  cleaned_sentence = []
  for word in sentence.split(' '):
    if not re.search(r'\W'):
      cleaned_sentence.append(word)
  DSP1.append(' '.join(cleaned_sentence))

print(DSP1)
# ['i am in', 'this code is']
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `str.isalpha`

```
Input = ["i am in jersey1&2","this code is %bdn2*nn"]

for i in Input:
    print(" ".join(j for j in i.split() if j.isalpha()))
```

**Output:**

```
i am in
this code is
```